# Position icon top right hand corner of frame xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, absolutelayout

I would like to position an icon at the top right corner of a frame.
I have to admit that I read about absolute layout multiple times but obviously is not going in my head.

As you can see from the pic the icon is a bit out and this is the code

[image]

**Sample code that is wrong!**

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Frame
        Margin="10"
        Padding="10"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        BorderColor="Blue"
        CornerRadius="5"
        HasShadow="False">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="sample" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="sample2" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
    <ContentView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, -1, -1" 
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">

        <Image Source="myIcon.png" />
    </ContentView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your icon a specific width and height and set Frame's margin a proportional value. You can change Frame's margin value to make it fit as you like:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Frame
        Margin="10"
        Padding="10"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        BorderColor="Blue"
        CornerRadius="5"
        HasShadow="False">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Text="sample" />
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="sample2" />
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
    <Image AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1, 0, 25, 25"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
           Source="myIcon.png" Aspect="AspectFit" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply that did not work the icon totally dissappered

Comment: CORRECTION . The icon does not dissapear but appears inside the frame when I want to be on top of the right hand corner.

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you explain what you did. That worked

Comment: There needed to be an amount of space between AbsoluteLayout and Frame so that our icon be placed a little above and right of Frame which you already did it by setting a `Margin="10"` to Frame(The value needs to be nearly a half of the width/height value of the icon). Then we put the icon at top-right of AbsoluteLayout and gave a 25 value as its width and height.